# Set persistent systemwide Path in Win 10 Systemenvironment with Powershell

Tags: windows, powershell, environment-variables

I tried to do it the following way: logged in as Admin, opened cmd as admin

powershell.exe -executionpolicy bypass -command $new= ';C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application'; $env:path += $new ; write-output $env:path; [System.Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable('path',$env:path);$env:path

In this session I see the correct Path, opening a new cmd Window the old Path is unchanged.

Thanks for your help

Comment: It would help if you clarified your goal/purpose in your question. What exactly are you trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 1):

I think you're close enough, you just need to specify Machine scope:

```
[Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable("Path", $env:Path + ";C:\Dummy", "Machine")
```

This doesn't affect the existing Powershell/Cmd sessions, but any new sessions created after this should report `C:\Dummy` as part of their `env:$Path`.

Comment: I was unclear in the question. I would like to get a persistent new Path in the Win 10 environment. The presented hint ist not helping to solve this. I think I have to use setx command.

Comment: I've clarified how it works, does this help?